# EOF handling in Drozer (python) interactive session

Tags: java, android, python, terminal, eof

I try to code a Java program which uses  Drozer (a tool written in Python to test vulnerabilities in Android app). I need to execute commands directly from Java and so far everything goes pretty well, but I have a problem when an interavtive session of drozer starts. It seems that the problem occurs when EOF needs to be handled, since ctrl + D also can't stop the session. Here is what I get after hitting ctrl + D

```
*** Unknown syntax: EOF
```

Here is the code I use to connect from Java to Drozer, after running it, my program starts infinite loop printing the same error: *** Unknown syntax: EOF.
Any other command works like a charm. Any ideas what do I do wrong?

Cheers

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

       List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
       List<String> commands1 = new ArrayList<String>();
       commands.add("/usr/local/bin/drozer");
       commands.add("console");
       commands.add("connect");
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
       pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
       try {

          Process prs = pb.start();
          Thread inThread = new Thread(new In(prs.getInputStream()));
          inThread.start();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          OutputStream writeTo = prs.getOutputStream();
          writeTo.write("oops\n".getBytes());
          writeTo.flush();
          writeTo.close();

       }catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace(); 
       }
   }
}

class In implements Runnable {
    private InputStream is;

    public In(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int size = 0;
            while ((size = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                 System.out.println(new String(b));
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(In.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   
    }
}
```